# 4-bit ALU, 5-bit output. VHDL

Tags: vhdl, quartus

Good day. I want to make a 4-bit ALU but with 5-bit output.
However, it gives a size error:

> Error (10344): VHDL expression error at alu.vhd(59): expression has 4 elements, but must have 5 elements

The ALU works perfectly when `a` and `b` are 5 bits, but the idea is that they are 4 bits:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity alu is 
port(
        s: in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        al: in std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
        bl: in std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
        rl: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
        f: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0)
        );
end alu;

architecture comportamiento of alu is
    
    component multiplicador
    port(
        a: in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        b: in std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
        ci: in std_logic;
        co: out std_logic;
        r: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0)
        );
        end component;
    
    signal ri: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
    signal com: std_logic;
    signal am: std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
    signal bm: std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    
begin

    am(0)<=al(0);
    am(1)<=al(1);
    am(2)<=al(2);
    bm(0)<=bl(0);
    bm(1)<=bl(1);
    
    m0: multiplicador port map (
    a=> am, 
    b=> bm,
    ci=> '0',
    co=> com,
    r=> ri 
    );
    
    rl<= ri;
    
    with s select
    f<=     al+bl       when "000",
            al-bl       when "001",
            ri          when "010",
            al or bl    when "011",
            al xor bl   when "100",
            al and bl   when "101",
            "00000"     when others;

end comportamiento;
```

I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Which line is line 59?

Comment: Also, most values have 5 bits here, I don't see any with 4 bits.

Comment: You don't use package numeric_std appearing in a use clause  in the shown alu.vhd. Line 59: contains `"00000"     when others;` where the expression has the right number of elements. Your message doesn't match the code you provide.  In a simulator allowing top level ports and with a default values of "000" to "101" and "111" (invoking the others choice) on `s` no simulation errors occur (matching elements is a requirement encountered during signal update during simulation, see IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update). You appear to have a procedural error using your Quartus tools.